# Debug JSF Phase with Seam 3 / Seam Faces

Tags: debugging, jsf-2, seam, seam3

I'm trying to resolve a weird behavior in my application, and to help me I would like to debug the JSF phases (i.e display the sequence)

I use **Seam 3** with the **SeamFaces** Module.

I've trying to use the **@Observes** annotation as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/events.html#events.phases), without success,

My class :

```
// @Named ? With or without, it doesn't work.
public class PhaseListener {

    public void observeBefore(@Observes @Before PhaseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Before phase :"+e.getPhaseId().toString());
    }

    public void observeAfter(@Observes @After PhaseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("After phase :"+e.getPhaseId().toString());
    } 

}
```

Problem : I've set a breakpoint inside the functions, but this code is never executed.

Anybody could help me to achieve this objective?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a beans.xml in your WEB-INF? My guess is your WAR isn't being considered a bean archive so CDI isn't picking up your observers.